# t test in R to see if mean 1 is lower than mean 2

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

How do I compute a test in R to see if, in the AML group of the golub dataset, the mean expression value for gene 808 is lower than the mean expression value for gene 1042?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data are approximately normal and the sample sizes
are moderately large, there should be no problem using a t test to
test $H_0: \mu_{808} = \mu_{1042}$ against $H_0: \mu_{808} < \mu_{1042}.$

I will use fake data because I do not have immediate access to your real data, but
the method of doing the test in R would be the same. I would use the Welch
two-sample t test, because I have no reason to suppose that the two 'expression values' have the same variance.

```
set.seed(1310)
x.808 = rnorm(500, 55, 7)
x.1042 = rnorm(450, 57, 8)
t.test(x.808, x.1042, alt="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x.808 and x.1042
t = -3.5065, df = 905.96, p-value = 0.0002382
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
       -Inf -0.9124708
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 55.11405  56.83431 

boxplot(x.808, x.1042, col="skyblue2", pch=20, names=c("808","1042"))
```

[image]

The two boxplots look similar, but sample sizes are large enough to distinguish between the two means. Notice that the boxplots show some 'outliers', but
this is to be expected with normal samples of this size. The presence of
a few (fairly near) outliers is no contraindication for using the Welch t test.